# VB. Net - How to automatically reload web page on server error

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

Im developing a web browser. Whenever I try to navigate to a particular site, if there's a server error like "page taking too long to respond", "server busy/overloaded" etc. I want the error to get displayed in a message box and then the page I had tried to navigate must automatically refersh, as a second attempt.

I know the web browser itself displays the error message in the browser form but I want to diplay the error message in a messge box for some reason and then reload the page. Is there any way to do it?

If there's no way to copy the error to a message box, at least is there any way my program can automatically refresh the page if there's a server error?

Comment: You'll need to have a Try/Catch around the whole page_load event - and if you catch ANY exception, instead of letting ASP show it, you can route to a custom page or just show a box, etc